# Is it a good practice in protobuf3 using optional to check nullability?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I noticed that they bring `optional` back in protobuf 3.15. I'm trying to use `optional` to check field presence. But I'm still unclear regarding the philosophy behind this.

Here is  my usecase:

I'm providing some services that accept `protobuf` as my input. But **the client side is untrusted from my perspective**, therefore I have to check the nullability for the input protobuf.

The way I expect is that,

- for a required field, either it's set, or it's null,
- for an optional field, I don't care I can just use a default value and that won't cause any problem from my system

So I end up adding `optional` to every field that should not be null so that I can use `hasXXX` to check the presence. This looks weird to me because those fileds are actually `required` from my perspective, but I have to add `optioanl` keyword for them all.......I'm not sure whether this is a good practice. Proto experts pls give me some suggestions.

Also the default value doesn't make sense to me at all regarding nullability checking, since zero or empty string usually have their own meaning in many scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire point of `optional` in proto3 is to be able to distinguish between, for example:

1. no value was specified for field `Foo`
2. the field `Foo` was explicitly assigned the value that happens to be the proto3 default (zero/empty-string/false/etc)

In proto3 without `optional`: the above both look identical (which is to say: the field is omitted)

If you don't need to distinguish between those two scenarios: you don't *need* `optional`, but using `optional` also isn't likely to hurt much - worst case, a few extra zero/empty-string/false values get written to the wire, but *they're small anyway*.

Answer (score 3):

[Google's API Design guide](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3) discourages the usage of the `optional` keyword. Better practice is to make use of the `google.api.field_behavior` annotation for describing the field's behaviour.

It is however not recommended to use the optional annotation at all [[1](https://linter.aip.dev/203/optional-consistency)]. If one consistently implements the field behaviour annotations then `OPTIONAL` is redundant and can be omitted.

Check out [AIP 203](https://google.aip.dev/203) for an overview of the various behaviour types along with [guidelines around the usage of `OPTIONAL` fields](https://linter.aip.dev/203/optional-consistency).

In general, [Google's API Improvement Proposals](https://google.aip.dev/) are a great reference for good practices in your API design.

Comment: The `google.api.field_behaviour=OPTIONAL` is different from the protobuf `optional` keyword, and cannot serve as a replacement. The latter allows you to distinguish default primitive values from unset values, while the former does not.

Comment: Of course this is not a replacement, they are for different purposes. `google.api.field_behaviour=OPTIONAL`, `google.api.field_behaviour=REQUIRED` are for documenting APIs. `optional` is NOT for documenting but for building logic based on field presence information (which is generally considered a bad practice)